# Visual Studio 2012 linking issues

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, lnk2019, lnk2005

Visual Studio seems to be going wild recently. I am working on a simple c++ project, which includes one header with definitions + cpp file with declarations. That's it. Simple include guard, .h is included in both source files. Now i find myself breaking my head over linking problems. Sometimes is just compiles and says everything is ok, and sometimes keeps on throwing LNK2019 - although no changes to the structure of the project have been made. Suddenly, out of nowhere it decides to compile, and after a few changes comes back to the initial state. I have described this problem down in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752259/lnk-2019-unresolved-external-symbol-again) topic, but the problem has solved itself. I must also note that i have simplified the file structure to the minimum. Tried cleaning, rebuilding, pretty much any tool in VS. Has anyone else came across such issues?

Comment: It may compile fine but not build (that's when you'll get linker errors). You missing a lib file?

Comment: Try doing a batch build and building everything available. Build (From the top menu) -> Batch Build -> Select All -> Rebuild.

Comment: not at all. I can compile each file on its own, but that doesnt get me anywhere.

Comment: I'm afraid batch didn't work ;/

Comment: @Ghostli So did it fail on the debug or release or both?

Comment: I have posted entire project on pastebin - feel free to try compiling it on your own : http://pastebin.com/dAcz0mPY http://pastebin.com/kUuSCKLL http://pastebin.com/ZNk2WgxC You would also need to include sqlite, or just dump the body of the functions.

Comment: both. Well i was working on it just an hour ago, added one more variable in some spot...and it's all over again. Duh